# Add depencency to group of gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, build-process, build.gradle

I have a project with a bunch of publishing tasks:

```
Publishing tasks
----------------
generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'mavenJava'.
generatePomFileForMavenPublication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'maven'.
publish - Publishes all publications produced by this project.
publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'mavenJava' to the local Maven repository.
publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'mavenJava' to Maven repository 'maven'.
publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'maven' to the local Maven repository.
publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'maven' to Maven repository 'maven'.
publishToMavenLocal - Publishes all Maven publications produced by this project to the local Maven cache.
```

Now I want all of these tasks to be dependent on `build`, to ensure tests and checks are run before anything is published (by default publishing tasks are dependent on `assemble`).

Of course the following works:

```
publish.dependsOn(build)
publishToMavenLocal.dependsOn(build)
```

But it is cumbersome to maintain and it does not work for any generated task like `publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository`. **Is there a way to add a dependency to all publishing tasks?** Of course I tried `publishing.dependsOn(build)` but then it just says:

```
Could not find method dependsOn() for arguments [task ':build'] on org.gradle.api.publish.internal.DefaultPublishingExtension_Decorated@5b5f8cd6.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no possibility to define a *group* dependency, however you can try:

```
tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith('publish') }*.dependsOn(DA_TASK)
```

Comment: Well this is actually what I was looking for, thanks! I had read it somewhere before, but forgot about the findAll function. By the way, it turns out the tasks I mentioned like `publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository` are not included in the findAll. Apparently they are generated later or something similar. I wonder if anyone knows why?

Comment: Some tasks are not present during configuration time, only in later phases. Try to run the code in the answer in `project.afterEvaluate { //HERE }`, all the tasks should be present there.